# Select divs by ID prefix in d3

Tags: d3.js

I have a bunch of divs with the following ids:

`<div id = "abox"></div>`

`<div id = "bbox"></div>`

`<div id = "cbox"></div>`

I would like to select all of these divs using d3, something like

`d3.selectAll("# *box)` where * indicates any string. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not use a class instead of an ID? E.g. `d3.select(".star-box")` for `<div id="abox" class="star-box">`, etc.

Comment: i didn't include this in my code but the divs all have classes already

Comment: The `<div>`s can each have multiple classes, just separate them with a space.

Comment: Glad to help! Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a class to each of those `<div>`s, and then select them using a class selector. (Note that elements can have multiple classes, just separate them with a space.) Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="abox" class="class1 class2 star-box">...</div>
<div id="bbox" class="class1 class3 star-box">...</div>
<div id="cbox" class="class2 class4 star-box">...</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var divs = d3.selectAll(".star-box")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select all divs and then use the `filter` method on the collection to do this.

```
d3.selectAll('div').filter(function(){
  return d3.select(this).attr('id').substr('box') !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `[id*="box"]`, if d3 uses all the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).